# Spring boot handle null values of Database

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using SPring provided JPA dependency to list all items from User table. Some users doest have phone numbers in database and i am getting below error. Any way to ignore null values of DB?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field com.freelancer.Entity.User.phone to null value
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:80) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
```

Entity class is like below:

```
@Table(name = "user")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;


    private long phone;
    private String about;
    private int profile_id;
    private String skills;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitive types like `long` cannot have null values. Suggest you to change `phone` type to `Long`. Also when you access you can do null check.